# iOS Touch, Gestures, Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation

I am exploring iOS4.3 SDK & wanted to implement a particular animation effect. But have no idea how to do it. It goes like this - I have a square box on the screen & upon user putting his finger on the box & dragging his finger the box should follow him. It's easy till here. I was able to implement it like so -

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches 
          withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch   = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    CGAffineTransform scaleTrans  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    CGAffineTransform rotateTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle * M_PI / 180);
    boxView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTrans, rotateTrans);
    angle             = (angle == 180 ? 360 : 180);
    scaleFactor       = (scaleFactor == 2 ? 1 : 2);
    boxView.center    = location;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But as the user lifts his finger, I want the box to carry on with the motion (as if with momentum). It's like the same rubber band scrolling effect apple implements; even when u leave scrolling, the screen scrolls & slowly comes to a stop. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you consider using [`UIPanGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can use the `translationInView:` to move the box as moves the finger across. And when the gesture's `state` is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, you could use `velocityInView:` to get the desired follow up effect.

Comment: so `velocityInView` keeps moving my box even as I lift my finger. Gradually slowing the box to a standstill?

Comment: It gives you points per second in which the user was moving the box. You can use some kind of decceleration rate to calculate where it will reach when it slows down and animate the box to that location over a period of time.

Comment: cool! thanks. Do you have some sample code I could look at? or else I'll figure it out...

Comment: Nothing at hand for simulating the momentum. The deceleration thing will have to be a trial and error thing though.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    CGPoint velocityPoint = [recognizer velocityInView:yourView];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];



    [yourView setCenter:CGPointMake(yourView.center.x + (velocityPoint.x/4), yourView.center.y + (velocityPoint.y/4))];

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:yourView];


   [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Hope this will help someone :)