# iOS - How to make an animation track touches

Tags: ios, core-animation

What is the best way to implement a smooth reversing animation which tracks touches?  I am referring to those animations in which, for example, if the user executes a swipe gesture some elements smoothly animate on screen, and others off, **but** if the user instead slowly drags a pan gesture back and forth the same objects will move forward/backward as a percent in accordance with the touch position.  This is seen in many app intros and also in transitions.  I have found

- One tutorial which discusses the built-in facility for this but it is only between view controller transitions, not providing the full granular control I see in many apps (http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/)
- Jazzhands, which is a kit by IFTTT, but this is a packaged solution that might not cover how the solution is best implemented at a lower level (https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands)
- A question here for which one answer shows how you might execute an animation after a gesture ends ([iOS Touch, Gestures, Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225387/ios-touch-gestures-animation))

What I don't grasp - and I'm comfortable using CAAnimations and gestures - is how something can be both *animated* **and** *interactive*.

Typically, when I create an animation, I commit the animation and it goes from start to finish.  While I could interrupt the animation as touches continue, that seems like it would be stilted.

On the other hand, moving things in response to user input is easy, but that is not animated.

How is the effect achieved where something can change according to an animation, but also have that exact same animation occur tied to touches, *and yet still also* have it so that although the animation reaches completion it doesn't really "finish" (become irreversible) unless the user releases touch, while at any point during interaction if the user releases panning then the animation either reverts backwards to its starting position or animates to completion depending on the last touch location and velocity.  These requirements are baffling.

The glimpses of this technique I see all involve keyframe animations, but what I don't understand is *where* the touch events intersect with an animation to create these smooth effects I see.

Any tips, examples, or tutorials are most welcome.

Comment: This question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4720122/189804 - and its answers might help you. You can define an animation and move the animation along a path by changing the timeOffset property of an object conforming to CAMediaTiming.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What I don't grasp - and I'm comfortable using CAAnimations and gestures - is how something can be both animated and interactive.

It is because, having set up an animation, you can set that animation to any "frame" you wish. Thus you can track the animation in correspondence to the movement of a gesture.

The way this works is that an animation is a feature of the render tree, belonging to a CALayer. CALayer implements the CAMediaTiming protocol. The `timeOffset` of a CALayer thus determines what "frame" of an animation that layer displays. If a complex animation involves many different layers, no problem; just set the `timeOffset` of their mutual superlayer, to control the frame of the entire animation.

That in fact is exactly how the new iOS 7 interactive custom transition feature works (to which you rightly refer in your question). For instance, in this example code:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch06p296customAnimation2/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m

... I keep updating the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition to tell it how far through the gesture the user is, and the animation therefore tracks the gesture. Now ask yourself: how the heck is this possible???

Well, the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition, in turn, behind the scenes, keeps adjusting the layer's `timeOffset` to portray the animation at the corresponding frame. (You can actually add logging code to my example to see that this is true.)

Moreover, when I end the gesture at an incomplete point, the animation either hurries to its end or runs backwards to its beginning - again, this is because of the CAMediaTiming protocol, which lets you change the `speed` of the animation, including a negative value to run it backwards.

Comment: And here's a very nice tutorial on this topic: http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/ Once you understand about this - once the penny drops, as it were - a whole new world opens up.

Comment: And see this tech note from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html

Comment: That tutorial is money.  I can't believe how much simpler this actually is than I thought it would be.  I would never have thought to use the timeOffset+speed properties this way, but now it's so obvious and yet brilliant.  I feel I've done some pretty cool things in my apps but apps employing this technique always feel **so** smooth and well-polished to interact with.  I can't wait to master it.  Thank you very much Matt.