# iOS 7+ partial swipe to back issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7

In my app I am partially swiping my ViewController and swiping back to the same view. While doing this `viewDidLoad` is not getting called. But if I swipe fully and come back to the view again, `viewDidLoad` gets called. It is creating some issue.

So even if I swipe partially and stay in the same view `viewDidLoad` needs to be called (currently only `viewWillAppear` is getting called). How to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to call the `viewDidLoad` method of the second view if it is swiped halfway and returned back?

Comment: The problem I am facing is, once I half swipe and land on the same view the back button (in navigation bar) stops working but if I go back fully and come again back action works fine. The only difference I am seeing between these two scenario is didload call... So I want it to be called in half swipe also

Comment: I had a similar problem to yours, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261304/navigation-bar-title-bug-with-interactivepopgesturerecognizer

Comment: It makes sense ... Thank you very much.. Will try the steps..

Answer (score 0):

Half swipe of the back button is just like a back to the previous viewcontroller. When you half swipe the viewcontroller and again come to that viewcontroller **viewdidload** will never be called.
Its better you put the **swipegesture disable**.

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: I need it :-( .. Any other options?

Comment: Its not possible bro. If you take your custom back button and swipegesture than also the same thing will happen. Its a feature of iOS.

Comment: Its not possible bro. If you take your custom back button and swipegesture than also the same thing will happen. Its a feature of iOS.